# perl6 Thread reading interference

Tags: multithreading, raku

I need to have multiple threads each read from the same socket or from
$*IN; however, there seems to be error because each is trying to read from the same source (I think). What is the best way to resolve this problem? Thanks !!

```
my $x = start { prompt("I am X: Enter x: "); }
my $y = start { prompt("I am Y: Enter y: "); }

await $x, $y;
say $x;
say $y;
```

And here are the errors:

```
I am X: Enter x: I am Y: Enter y: Tried to get the result of a broken Promise
  in block <unit> at zz.pl line 4

Original exception:
    Tried to read() from an IO handle outside its originating thread
      in block  at zz.pl line 1
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the latest development snapshot of Rakudo, your code actually works without throwing any exception on my system...
However, it still immediately asks for both values (`I am X: Enter x: I am Y: Enter y:`).

To make the second `prompt` wait until the first one has completed, you could use a [`Lock`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Lock):

```perl6
#--- Main code ---

my $x = start { synchronized-prompt "I am X: Enter x: "; }
my $y = start { synchronized-prompt "I am Y: Enter y: "; }

await $x, $y;
say $x.result;
say $y.result;


#--- Helper routines ---

BEGIN my $prompt-lock = Lock.new;

sub synchronized-prompt ($message) {
    $prompt-lock.protect: { prompt $message; }
}
```

The tricky part is that the lock needs to be initialized *before* the threads start using it concurrently. That's why I call `Lock.new` *outside* of the `synchronized-prompt` subroutine, in the mainline of the program. Instead of doing it at the top of the program, I use a [`BEGIN` phaser](https://docs.perl6.org/language/phasers#BEGIN) so that I can place it next to the subroutine.

Comment: Thank you smls !! I updated Rakudo and the error disappeared. And I will also look into the Lock class. Thank you very much !!